# using browser logos

Tags: html, jsp, browser, graphical-logo

I'm adding a functionality of browser version detection and showing a message if the version is outdated, just like Youtube is doing for IE6. 
Is it OK to use the logos of all the browsers? And where can I find the logos for using in my web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find them in the code sample at http://ie6nomore.com.

Answer (score 1):

The logos you can find on their respective websites, or a Google Image search will yield several you can use. You have to include the standard "trademarked by xyz" for you to use the legally, but I doubt there would be a problem if you used them without permission since the browsers are (mostly) popular and in the public eye IF they do sue you for copyright you could argue that you're doing them a service and that your website is geared for the latest version only.

Comment: I couldn't find the logo of Google chrome in their web site. I did an image search but didn't help.

Comment: Microsoft have all the browser logos for their http://www.browserchoice.eu/ website. I can't see any obvious copyrights, except their own through two clicks, and I imagine they'd be paranoid about that.